# How to handle the device watcher "cache" of old devices on start-up?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

I have one BLE application.
When I start the device scanning, the `DeviceWatcher.Added` event will call immediately and shows the previously connected devices which is currently powered off. But in the `DeviceWatcher.Removed` event it will be cleared.

How can I prevent this situation. In my application I am trying to connect the device immediately when ever there is the device listed in the `DeviceWatcher.Added` event. I don't want to wait till the `DeviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted` event.

Because of this implementation, the connection API `BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLEDevice = BluetoothLEDevice::FromIdAsync(GetId()).get();` is returning success. And in the service scan API `GattDeviceServicesResult result = m_BluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode::Uncached).get();` I am getting `GattCommunicationStatus::Unreachable` status.

I need this status in the initial time of scanning. Or there is any other way I can check the device is unreachable or not?

Comment: The right way to discover (find) BLE devices is using BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.

Answer (score 1):

**The sample written here is in C#, you could find the C++ replacement in the [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/)**

- You could get all the paired BLE devices like this.

```
var pairedBleDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true)); # Return all the paired Bluetooth LE devices
```

Now, if you want to remove the pairing of a specific device, you could loop through the pairedBleDevices and find your removal device by matching specific property, let's say device name or address.

```
foreach (var device in pairedBleDevices )
{
    if (!device::Name.Contains("myDevice")) continue;
    await device.Pairing.UnpairAsync();
    break;
}
```

- Now, as you have all the previously paired LE devices with properties, as Mike suggested, you could use BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher to discover BLE devices and filter the advertisement by matching the BluetoothAddress(from the paired device). If you find a new device, pair the device or execute the GATT operation and start communicating.
- You are getting GattCommunicationStatus::Unreachable that's probably the device you are trying to communicate with is in sleep mode. So the best way is to capture the advertisement first using BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher and, after that, initiate the pairing or GATT operation.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the answer is pretty much in your question. As with the other answer this is in C# but easily convertible;

```
private async void HandleFoundDevice(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation e)
{
    var id = e.Id;

    var bluetoothLEDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(id);

    GattDeviceServicesResult gatServiceAsync = await bluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);

    if (gatServiceAsync.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
    {
        // add your device to your list / invoke a call back to your caller somewhere / etc.
    }
}
```

And just add this handle to the device watcher;

```
mDeviceWatcher.Added += HandleFoundDevice;
```

It may be possible to do this in the filter when you create the watcher but I can't get it to work. It may have something to do with the bluetooth cache. It feels buggy from Windows side. But the code above prevents the behavior described by OP.